# Entry query on field using the `and` parameter

Tags: craft3, entries, query, tags

I'm struggling to get a `and` entry query to work - it seems to be stuck on `or`.

Query is `{% set blogQ = blogQ.blogTags(['and', blogTag|join(",")]) %}` where `blogTag` is `[2291,2290]` in this case. This would translate to `{% set blogQ = blogQ.blogTags(['and',2291,2290]) %}`

In this instance I get 0 results.

If I change to use `{% set blogQ = blogQ.blogTags(blogTag) %}` then I'll get entries that have the tag id of 2291 OR 2290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `join(",")` as it is returning a `string` of your values, something like `"123, 456"` instead of a comma separated list of `int` as you expect.

Try this:

```twig
{# Create an array starting in 'and` #}
{% set relatedTags = ['and'] %}

{# Merge your ids in your relatedTags array #}
{% set blogQ = blogQ.blogTags(relatedTags | merge(blogTag)) %}
```

See documentation for the [`merge` filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#merge).

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now.  
So the query I was trying would actually look like:  
`{% set blogQ = blogQ.blogTags(['and',"2291,2290"]) %}`?

Comment: Yes! That's it :)